# Is this mold on my AC vent?

Tags: air-conditioning, mold

[image]

I went to close the AC vent in the apartment we're renting and saw this. Is this mold or just many years of dust buildup? If it is mold, can I safely just remove the vent and wash it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely mold.  Yes you can clean it off - use a mixture of bleach and water.

I would however be concerned with the original cause. If you don't fix this, it will just happen all over again.